# How to create a graph for a semantic web service data set

Tags: networking, semantics, diagram, semantic-web, similarity

I have a dataset for a semantic web service and I would like to create a graph with this dataset.

I have found some sample graph results such as this:

[image: sample graph]

Do you know what program made this? Or do you have any suggestion for a program to create something like that using my dataset?

A sample of my dataset:

- C0 : C1
- C2 : C1
- C3 : C0
- …

Answer (score 1):

[Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/) has a decent visual editor for such graphs. It looks different but you can use it to create something similar. Easy JPG and PNG export is available as well.

As for the graph in your question. It looks similar to some [NavigOWL](http://klatif.seecs.nust.edu.pk/navigowl/index.html) output I've seen on the project's official website (NavigOWL is available as a Protégé plugin BTW):

[image]

**You can find it (as well as some more examples) [here](http://klatif.seecs.nust.edu.pk/navigowl/gallery.html)**